# DataTable: How can I add custom buttons manual in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I'm new to learn DataTable and I want to create manual customized in html of my table.

I know how to add elements in JS but how can I add buttons and search in HTML in manually same place like can I add in JS by DataTable and additionally I want that they would work in same way like they can be make in JS.

```
buttons: [
        'pdf',
        'pageLength',
        'colvis',
        /*{
        text: 'Add',
        name: 'add' 
      },*/
      {
        extend: 'selected', 
        text: 'Edit',
        name: 'Edit'        
      },
      {
        extend: 'selected', 
        text: 'Delete',
        name: 'delete'      
     },
     ]
```

How can i make this buttons in html with same actions like in specifications and place in DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable provides an API you can tap into to add your own custom search fields/filtering

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search
```

A full example is available here: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[3] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && age <= max ) ||
         ( min <= age   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= age   && age <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
} );
```

Comment: but i mean about buttons "add/edit/pdf etc" as i add in code.. ho can i creat this buttons in html in each file separately.